# Terminating app due to uncaught 'NSUnknownKeyException',

Tags: iphone

keep getting this error for this code
I used breakpoints it crashes at

```
GameSelect *selectGame = [[GameSelect alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

I don't know what's going on
i am simply switching from one nib to another nib

```
- (IBAction)playButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    GameSelect *selectGame = [[GameSelect alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    selectGame.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:selectGame animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your initWithNibName is set to nil. You should put a name for your nib.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your nib file name here: GameSelect *selectGame = [[GameSelect alloc] initWithNibName:@"" bundle:nil];

Answer (score 0):

Make it as follows,

```
- (IBAction)playButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    GameSelect *selectGame = [[GameSelect alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameSelect" bundle:nil];
    selectGame.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:selectGame animated:YES];
}
```

If your nib name is any other name instead of "GameSelect" give "your nib name".